# Finding Miracast deivces using WifiDirect api (c++)

Tags: c++, wifi-direct, wifip2p, miracast

I am trying to find all Miracast devices (like smart TV that supports Miracast).

How i can do that from desktop c++ software (not app)?

I would like to do that from win7 and from win10

I read about WiFiDirectService class but i am not sure this is the right way or what is the service name

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please consider adding your code to let it get elaborated in a better way.

Comment: Hi. I do not have any code since i do not find where to start. All idea of this question is to get some suggestion where to look for ...